# Is it possible to add the same custom menu to every new google document? The goal is to make a local script function like an installed app

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

Is it possible to add the same custom menu to every new google document? The goal is to make a local script function like an installed app.

This seems like it should be easy but I can't seem to find a way to do it. I'm using a standard account for personal use. I've created a script attached to the original document and also made copy as a stand alone script. (I'm not sure that makes a difference.) I've searched and read about deployment and it seems to be only useful for a domain account or publicly as an app. I've played a little with scripting but this is the first attempt to get a script working "globally".

Any help will be most appreciated.

Comment: The best you could do is to create and addon.  But it will still require each used to find it, install it and authorize it.

Comment: Thanks Cooper. Please see the response to the answers below. The first addresses your comment. Perhaps you have some ideas regarding either.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do this in an old example at:  https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/custom-methods/2d-arrays-library.

The script is in a project and that needs to be connected to the current doc. The onOpen() script is a UI that contains the line:

.addItem('Select Phrase', 'PS.showPrompt')

where PS is the name of the attached library. Once this is done, as you said, you can make a copy and use it with the script active.

It is a little slow as they describe about using a library, but is make the code easier to maintain. Thanks to all for the direction to look.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a [Google Docs Add-On](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/editors/docs) using an independent [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) script and then install your Add-On globally. For more information regarding its installation check [this documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2942256?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en). However you would need to run this Add-On on the new documents to get your desired menu.

Comment: I really only need this for my own use. The add-on process seems complicated, the demands are excessive and apparently requires Google approval.  There is a mention of "Editor" add-ons but I can't find any documentation that doesn't refer to  Google Suites. Do you have anything that may clarify? BTW. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What we do is create a copy of the original document (the document with the attached google apps script). The script is copied along with it and the copied document has the exact same functionality (menus, custom functions, etc).

Comment: Thank you. I tried to this and it worked, however, I believe that it creates a copy of the script for each document making updating really difficult since there may be 10's of occurrences. I tried to add the onOpen() to the new document and connected the library that holds the rest of the code. Interestingly, it asked for authorization (probably for the UI) but wouldn't find the the function specified in the UI. This process would be acceptable since most of the code is in the library available for maintenance. Any ideas how to make this work?

Comment: I found a way to do this in an old example at:  https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/custom-methods/2d-arrays-library

Comment: It indeed creates a separate script for the new sheet and you are right that you would need to update each script when you change the script. You can create an add-on that is limited to your domain, this way you don't need to go through approval for the marketplace. You could do that if your personal account is under your own domain, like gary.com. I have done this for a domain and it works. I will check if I can replicate it with my personal gmail.com account.

Comment: I tried to publish an internal add-on with my gmail account, but it won't let me: _Because you’re not a G Suite user, you can only make your app available to external (general audience) users_. About the copied script, yes, it would need new authorization (only once from each user) for a new (copied) document and script. I haven't worked with libraries, maybe you need a separate scope to use the libraries, so you can't use the libraries before authorization. In this case, your pre-authorization menu shouuldn't use library functions and you should have a separate menu for after authorization.